# How to make SVG image elements clickable to show popup in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

Here is my code =. i have tried a lot. this section shows the svg image in which will be load in the container section.
**admin.component.html**(Contains SVG image)

```html
<div class = "container" style="text-align: center; position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img class="center1" type="image/svg+xml" src="assets/1.jpg" width="500px"/>  
    <img class="center2" type="image/svg+xml" src="assets/preserve.svg" width="500px"/>  
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**popup.component.html**(Popup modal)

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                    Hello
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**(Here I am calling the function through the modal id'.)

```js
ngOnInit(){
    $("g").click(function(){                                 
        $("#popup").modal("show");
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an angular click handler to the `<img>` element? I don't think the fact that the image is SVG matters here.

Answer (score 0):

my assumption is, since you don't actually have the svg template in your `admin.component.html`,  jquery couldn't find the 'g' tag used inside the `svg`.

**Suggestion**

- add the click event handler on the `img` containing the `svg` (**Recommended**)

```
ngOnInit(){
    $('.center2').click(function(){                                 
        $("#popup").modal("show");
    });
}
```

- If you absolutely need to add the event handler on the `g` tag. Then add the svg template in place of  the `img` tag containing the `svg`. Just open your `svg` in any text editor and copy paste the code. It would look something 
  like this.

```
<div class = "container" style="text-align: center; position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img class="center1" type="image/svg+xml" src="assets/1.jpg" width="500px"/>  
    <svg class="center2" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g fill="white" stroke="green" stroke-width="5">
          <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />
          <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="25" />
        </g>
    </svg>
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Its not working actually. No event/error is generating in console.